# svn propset svn:auto-props : Setting multiple files for entire repository recursively, how?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I’d like to set the autoprops via the commandline for my repository (checked out via Tortoise SVN on a Win machine), so that it is inherited recursively by all the files in the repository.

In order to do that I wrote batch file:

```
svn propset svn:auto-props '
*.xxx=svn:eol-style=native;svn:needs-lock=yes
*.yyy=svn:eol-style=LF;svn:needs-lock=yes
' .
```

But it does not work and I do hot have any idea why. If I execute:

```
svn propset svn:auto-props '*.xxx=svn:eol-style=native;svn:needs-lock=yes' .
```

it can set it for that single filetype, no problem.

Can anyone help me on getting it right?

Thank you very much.

Best Regards, Seppel

P.S. If I add it separated to the commandline it produces the following output:

```
C:\Users\sw\SVN_Playground>svn propset svn:auto-props '*.xxx=svn:eol-style=native;svn:needs-lock=yes *.yyy=svn:eol-style=LF;svn:needs-lock=yes' .
'*.yyy=svn:eol-style=LF;svn:needs-lock=yes'' is not under version control
svn: E155010: The node 'C:\Users\sw\SVN_Playground\needs-lock=yes'' was not found.
```

Comment: What does `svn proplist -v` show? Incidently, I find it easier to manipulate multi line properties using `svn propedit svn:auto-props .`

Comment: I assume the batch throws an error, but Windows closes the window immediately. So it does not change the svn properties at all.  

If I execute: svn propset svn:auto-props '*.xxx=svn:eol-style=native;svn:needs-lock=yes' .   

\SVN_Playground>svn proplist -v  
Properties on '.':  
  svn:auto-props  
    '*.xxx=svn:eol-style=native;svn:needs-lock=yes'

Comment: P.S. How would you solve it with "propedit"? Could you do an example please?